# Add value to checkbox field

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a checkbox field on a Notes document that identifies the steps completed in a process. If the user enters a value in the TestDate field, I would like it to check the box for "Tested" in the Tasks field. For some reason, I can't figure out how to add the value if other checkboxes are already checked.

I've tried setting it using formula language in validation (@SetField), putting it as a back-end field change in the LotusScript QuerySave and using LotusScript in the onChange event. I'm sure it's simple, but today I just can't get my head around it.

Comment: Hi - Could you clarify what you're trying to do?  The 2nd sentence says you want to check a box when a value is entered in a TestDate field.  The 3rd sentence makes it sound like there's an entirely different issue.  Thx

Comment: Ken, I want the value in the Tasks checkbox field to include a check mark for "Tested" if they enter a date for TestDate. I'm indifferent as to whether this occurs in the UI or after the document has been saved, just so that if there is a value in TestDate that one of the values checked in Tasks is "Tested". There are multiple values in the Tasks field, so I don't want it to accidentally clear those when it checks "Tested".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LotusScript, you should be able to do something like this:

```
set item = doc.getFirstItem("Tasks")
call item.AppendToTextList("Tested")
call doc.save(true)
```

Comment: Ended up using that fragment to propel me into 'Dim testDate As String
 testDate = Source.FieldGetText ( "TestDate" )
 If Not testDate = "" Then
  If Not Source.FieldContains ( "Tasks", "Tested" ) Then
   Set taskitem = note.getFirstItem("Tasks")
   If taskitem.Values (0) = "" Then
    note.Tasks = "Tested"
   Else
    Call taskitem.AppendToTextList("Tested")
   End If
  End If
 End If'

Comment: Ended up using that fragment to propel me into modifying the QuerySave by adding `Dim testDate As String
 testDate = Source.FieldGetText ( "TestDate" )
 If Not testDate = "" Then
  If Not Source.FieldContains ( "Tasks", "Tested" ) Then
   Set taskitem = note.getFirstItem("Tasks")
   If taskitem.Values (0) = "" Then
    note.Tasks = "Tested"
   Else
    Call taskitem.AppendToTextList("Tested")
   End If
  End If
 End If`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use any of the methods you specified, but you need to preserve the existing values:

```
@SetField("Tasks"; Tasks:"Tested");
```

Answer (score 0):

checkbox: use formula for choices;

formula:

```
@SetField("checkbox";@GetField("QW"))

sub click (on button)
    Call ws.CurrentDocument.Document.ReplaceItemValue("QW",choices)

    Call ws.CurrentDocument.Refresh
end sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot understand what you're suggesting.